# variables from jquery to php and vice versa

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to pass variables from jquery to php and vice versa by using AJAX, but just can't do it! I've looked at dozens of similar question and examples and still wrestling with the same issue.

This is the part where i try to pass variables to php.

in main.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  doSearch();
});

function doSearch(){
  var inID = $('#inID').val();
  var memInd = $('#memInd').val();
  var t1 = $('#t1').val();
  var t2 = $('#t2').val();
  alert("ID: "+inID+"memIND: "+memInd);
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "index.php",
    data: { inID: inID, memInd: memInd , t1: t1, t2: t2} 
  });
}
```

index.php:

```
$inID = $_POST["inID"];
echo $inID
```

Comment: Have u tried sending the data in json format and in php reading the json after json_decode ?

Comment: This question is asked at least once a day..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I included the .js where I run the ajax function in to the same php-page which was receiving ($_POST) the values from UI input. After I made an separate search.php-page to receive the values everything worked fine. I also ended up using the shorter syntax with jquery post()

```
        $.post('search.php',{id:id, mem:mem, t1:t1, t2:t2},function(res){
            $("#result").html(res);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the quotes,

```
data: { "inID": inID, "memInd": memInd , "t1": t1, "t2": t2}
```

Comment: The quotes is optional

Answer (score 0):

Change `dataType: "HTML"` to `dataType: "json"` and let me know if it works :)
(or just delete that line entirely as $.ajax autodetects)

Additionally, [$.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) has a shorter syntax than $.ajax if you're not doing anything fancy, so you could just use the following

```
$.post("index.php", { inID: inID, memInd: memInd , t1: t1, t2: t2});
```

And while you're at it, it's good practice to quote your params as Sudip Pal mentions, but not necessary if your parameter name is strictly alphanumeric..

#### Debugging Round 1

Change the `doSearch()` Javascript function to the following:

```
function doSearch(){
    var inID = "inIdValue";
    var memInd = "memIndVal";
    var t1 = "t1Val";
    var t2 = "t2Val";
    alert("ID: "+inID+"memIND: "+memInd);
    $.post("index.php",
        {
            inID: inID, memInd: memInd , t1: t1, t2: t2
        },
        function(data) {
            $('body').html(data);
            $('body').append('<button onclick="doSearch()">Reload</button>');
        }
    );
}
```

Backup the file as index2.php, then delete everything inside index.php and replace it all with the following (just copy and paste):

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
die("</pre>");
?>
```

Then please paste the results :)

Comment: inside post is a Array()

Comment: does the array have anything in it? (more specifically does it have `[inID] => somvalue` ?)

Comment: when writing print_r($_POST['inID']); I get some error but it goes under html-elements so I can't see what it says.

Comment: does `[inID] => somvalue` show up when you do `print_r($_POST);` and then immediately after `die();`?

Comment: ok, I took all the working stuff away, so just the ajax function now and I get an error message saying "Notice: Undefined index: inID in C:\wamp\www\..."

Comment: Check out debugging round 1

Answer (score 0):

try this

SCRIPT :

```
$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "index.php",
          dataType: "json",
          data: { inID: inID, memInd: memInd , t1: t1, t2: t2} ,
          success : function(res){
             alert(res.inID);
          }
       });
```

in php file

```
echo json_encode($_POST);
```

Hope it will help

Comment: @user2126173 you checked console

Comment: ok, simplified the code a lot and now I get just a [] when following your example

Comment: whats the problem now

Comment: hmm, after removing the dataType: "json" -line I know also get an alert: "undefined"

Comment: print_r($_POST); in your php file

Comment: with "print_r($_POST);" I get "Array ( )"

Comment: echo json_encode($_POST); now you can set dateType:'json' and you can use these as a json object like res.inID

Comment: "echo json_encode($_POST);" gives "[]". How do I use res.inID in php?

Comment: if we send data: { inID: inID } so we need to res.inID.. are you getting my point?

Comment: Now I don't understand. How do I save the value of the Array[inID] to a variable in php?